# Android Emulator SD Card Problem

Tags: android

I have a problem with the Android Emulator and its SD card. I am developing an application that writes files to /sdcard. Everything works fine, until I exit the emulator by clicking its close button. After restart the files are empty (size 0), but still in the directory. Of course, they have not been empty as long as the emulator runs.

This looks like a failed sdcard unplug, like with usb stick. But I am not sure, how the emulator treats the card exactly. I am starting the emulator from Eclipse, and get an error at exit, when I close the emulator.

The problem did not exist before I updated my Android plugin. I could use all my files after restarting the emulator. Moreover, the problem does not occur on the real thing. I am using the most recent Android stuff, and Eclipse 3.5.

I already tried deleting my emulators and creating a new one. I also tried shutting the emulator down with the red telephone button, but that did never complete. Of course, my app is not a service and has no threads pending at shutdown.

Any ideas, you friendly people out there?

Answer (score 1):

I am currently seeing the same problem on mine using an API 4 emulator, but putting the apk on my actual android device it works fine.  It only happens if I close the emulator and restart using "Debug As" or "Run As".  My current workaround is to start the emulator before running / debugging my app... not shutting down the emulator prevents this from happening, although I wish I had a real fix.

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away by itself. I have no idea, what caused the healing. I did not do anything particular. I just continued working.

Thanks for your attention.